# Design do ReportViewer em asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Tenho uma página na qual preciso inserir apenas o desenho do ReportViewer na View e atribuir o relatório pronto para esse ReportViewer
Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: O RDLC já é o desenho e os dados. Acho que não tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Então @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Tentei fazer daquele jeito que você me passou mas não funcionou, deu erro na página. Eu tenho o relatório pronto já, e os metodos da consulta também, só preciso criar o reportviewer. Coisa que está dificil. :(

Comment: No seu lugar, eu desistiria disso e geraria o relatório em PDF mesmo.

Comment: Então @CiganoMorrisonMendez, o probelma é que o pessoal quer as 3 opções. :( Eu não posso jogar os arquivos de um projeto webforms que já está funcionando neste projeto mvc ? Vai funcionar ?

Comment: Pode. Já respondi isso algumas vezes sobre como fazer. Agora é sentar com o código e fazer funcionar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Beleza, qualquer coisa abro outra pergunta. Valeu.